# Difference between fireEvent.dblClick & fireEvent.doubleClick in testing library?

Tags: svelte, testing-library, svelte-testing-library

Question about 2 different methods exposed via `fireEvent` API in the react-testing-library.

- `fireEvent.dblClick`
- `fireEvent.doubleClick`

What's the difference? And is there a recommendation to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's zero difference.

The Web platform natively has only ["dblclick"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event) event. Given that `"doubleClick"` is such a commonly mistaken event name, `testing-library` just makes it an alias of `"dblClick"`.

[Source](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/2a9ee25dc4807616cbd854968d17d1839ae7219d/src/event-map.js#L368)